# How is DNS lookup performed in nodejs

Tags: node.js, dns, aws-lambda

We are facing a challenge with AWSlambda on node js, where DNS.resolve vs. dns.lookup are giving different results. Where former faulting more than latter. And http.client also fails with almost same frequency. I'm interested in understanding, how http module handles DNS lookup.

Comment: There is no `http.client` function in node.js.  What exact code are you using?

Comment: Sorry, went into direct module, I'm using http.get and other similar methods

Comment: Well, `http.get()` calls `lookupAndConnect()` in net.js which then calls `lookup()` in dns.js which then calls `cares.getaddrinfo()` which is in native code which calls `uv_getaddrinfo()` which has various platform implementaions.  Here are links to the [windows](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/766cd1f59d5adb03953656391e63b4186c9aff10/deps/uv/src/win/getaddrinfo.c#L257) and [unix](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/766cd1f59d5adb03953656391e63b4186c9aff10/deps/uv/src/unix/getaddrinfo.c#L138) implementations.  The source is all on github for you to analyze.

Comment: Thanks, that explains

Comment: So, is your question answered now or is there more to it?

Comment: Yup, answered. Thanks for assistance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.get()` calls `lookupAndConnect()` in net.js which then calls `lookup()` in dns.js which then calls `cares.getaddrinfo()` which is in native code which calls `uv_getaddrinfo()` which has various platform implementations. Here are links to the [windows](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/766cd1f59d5adb03953656391e63b4186c9aff10/deps/uv/src/win/getaddrinfo.c#L257) and [unix](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/766cd1f59d5adb03953656391e63b4186c9aff10/deps/uv/src/unix/getaddrinfo.c#L138) implementations. The [source is all on github](https://github.com/nodejs/node) for you to analyze.